# Do equipment questions belong on this site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I've noticed a few equipment purchasing questions on this site. Do questions related to choosing equipment belong here?

[What is a good scanner on a budget?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/186/what-is-a-good-scanner-on-a-budget)

[What image tablet can you recommend on a budget?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/52/what-image-tablet-can-you-recommend-on-a-budget)

Answer (score 5):

I'd say they are on-topic if they're used in on-topic context; and same should go also for software recommendations.

Comment: I would also add that the author **has to get really, really specific** about the problem they are trying to solve. Questions ask simply "What tablet should I buy" should be closed as not a real question. They are too vague to answer reasonably.

Answer (score 5):

I'd  say:

- Software recommendations are fine, both free and commercial
- Instead of hardware purchase recommendations, we should **generally** strive to provide **generic guides to identifying a suitable device for the OP's needs.** What attributes to look for; what price range to prepare for; what kind of place sells them at what kind of price; and so on. Purchase guidelines don't age as quickly as shopping recommendations do, and it's still possible to point out some actual devices in the text.

Exceptions should be

- hardware recommendations based on own personal experience ("I've been using the X-B10 for three years now and ....") which in my opinion have inherent value if written by a honest and competent person
- specialized tools for which there is no big market of choices.