# How are hardware shopping recommendations dealt with?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do equipment questions belong on this site?](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/do-equipment-questions-belong-on-this-site)

This question:

[What is a good scanner on a budget?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/186/what-is-a-good-scanner-on-a-budget)

is essentially asking for a shopping recommendation.

Now I don't mean to attack that question in any way - I am merely using it as an example, and I can totally understand the desire to simply get a good recommendation - but as far as I am aware, the general Stack Exchange policy towards shopping recommendations is that they are not wanted; what *is* wanted is generic advice on how to identify a good product according to one's needs.

Is there a defined policy for this on GraphicDesign.SE? If not, what should it be?

I personally am in favour of banning shopping recommendations, and working on solid general advice on how to identify a good scanner / tablet / monitor etc.

Comment: I see you emphasize the shopping aspect, but could also peek a related question: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22/do-equipment-questions-belong-on-this-site

Comment: @koiyu good point. I would tend to redirect all discussion to that question

Answer (score 0):

The [stackoverflow blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) essentially answered this question:

> there is a way to ask these questions that avoids the inherent problems with shopping recommendations. For example, let’s say you wanted — as I did — to buy a point-and-shoot camera that takes good low light photos. So we’re going to ask on photo.stackexchange.com, naturally!
>
> Here’s one way to ask:
>
> > Q: What’s the best low light point-and-shoot camera?
> >
> > A: Canon S90 and Lumix LX3.
>
> Here’s another way to ask:
>
> > Q: How do I tell which point-and-shoot cameras take good low light photos?
> >
> > A: I strongly recommend looking for something with
> >
> > - a fast lens (2.0 at least)
> > - reasonable ISO handling (at least 400, but preferably 800)
> > - the biggest sensor available
> >
> > The sum of these factors are really critical for low light situations.

In short: If the question can outlast the product, it's acceptable to me.

Comment: This is a great quote, why not migrate it to the duplicate question http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22/do-equipment-questions-belong-on-this-site