# "Where to get/download X" questions

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, specific-question

There's a [question about finding a font to download/purchase](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26255/looking-for-myriad-pro-extra-light-used-by-apple) that is on the verge of being closed as Off Topic > Brainstorming/Idea gathering.

From what I'm reading about the question, the asker is looking for a specific font to download/purchase as opposed to using the typeface in an actual design.

Are shopping questions like this on-topic? I know there's already a question about [hardware shopping](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/do-equipment-questions-belong-on-this-site) asked and the verdict was that generic recommendations and software to fit specific need recommendations are fine. But this question seems rather specific, but still applicable to Graphic Design.

Answer (score 1):

If this were just a question asking where to buy a font, I would be on board with closing it as *too broad* as I typically do for shopping questions.

At first glance, this did look like a shopping question. However, I did not vote to close this particular question because there is added merit which is shown by the answers. I see it as more of a [font-identification](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification) question than a shopping question. I have changed the tags to reflect that.