# Is this a shopping or list question?

Tags: discussion

The billing software I use to keep track of my hours/clients/invoices etc. is no longer supported by the manufacturer, and I have to find something else. Is it off-topic here to ask for a suggestion? I could swear I had *seen* this question here already, but I'm not finding it.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/24/1976) seems to contain the conventional wisdom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you made the post already, but just for future reference:

---

[The answer](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24/1976) Abby links to is pretty old and dusty, but I think it still holds true today. As long as the recommendation question ties in with design (even on the business side of things) then I think the question has a welcome place in our community and can be categorized under [software-recommendations](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations)

Comment: ooh, good, I was looking for tags and didn't see that one. Someone added it already. Thanks! I tried to make the question answerable without being too opinion-based.